# MongoDB Compass Error - Expected “[” or AggregationStage but “{” found. when i try to use $sum inside $group

Tags: mongodb

Doing a simple $Sum aggregation results in the Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found. error.

```
{
   "_id":"1",
   "name":"stu1",
   "year":"2018",
   "marks":[
      {
         "m1":"60",
         "m2":"72",
         "m3":"80"
      }
   ]
}
```

> **My query**

```
 { 
     _id:"$year",  
     total:{
        $sum:{
          $add:[
                $toDouble:"$marks.m1",
                $toDouble:"$marks.m2"
               ]
              }   
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following

```
[{
    $unwind: "$marks"
},
{
$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  name: {
    $first: "$name"
  },
  year: {
    $first: "$year"
  },
  total: {
    $push: {
      $sum: {
        $add: [
          {
            $toDouble: "$marks.m1"
          },
          {
            $toDouble: "$marks.m2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
}]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N2FhRO7kHM5)